# My global and local coast map is not aligned with the map and not showing any sign of obstacle

Tags: ros, navigation, gazebo, rviz, simulation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVXsl.png)

[image]
[image]

HI,

I am currently build an AMR in which i am facing some errors in the navigation that is my local and global coast map is not proper shown and aligned in the rviz,it would be a great help if anyone can help me with it.i mentioned the necessary details below

coastmap_common_params.yaml

```
obstacle_range: 1.0
raytrace_range: 3.5

footprint: [ [0.35, 0.25], [0.35, -0.25], [-0.35, -0.25], [-0.35, 0.25] ]

#robot_radius: 0.105

inflation_radius: 1.0
cost_scaling_factor: 4.5

map_type: costmap
observation_sources: scan
scan: {sensor_frame: lidar_frame, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true}





gowtham@PG:~$ roslaunch neon_sub_6 neon_navigation1.launch
... logging to /home/gowtham/.ros/log/fad01176-e1cb-11ee-b44b-2f019aa116d8/roslaunch-PG-33571.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://PG:43507/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /DWAPlannerROS/acc_lim_theta: 9.0
 * /DWAPlannerROS/acc_lim_x: 4.5
 * /DWAPlannerROS/acc_lim_y: 4.5
 * /DWAPlannerROS/controller_frequency: 10.0
 * /DWAPlannerROS/forward_point_distance: 0.325
 * /DWAPlannerROS/goal_distance_bias: 20.0
 * /DWAPlannerROS/latch_xy_goal_tolerance: False
 * /DWAPlannerROS/max_scaling_factor: 0.2
 * /DWAPlannerROS/max_vel_theta: 2.65
 * /DWAPlannerROS/max_vel_trans: 0.27
 * /DWAPlannerROS/max_vel_x: 0.3
 * /DWAPlannerROS/max_vel_y: 0.3
 * /DWAPlannerROS/min_vel_theta: 0.9
 * /DWAPlannerROS/min_vel_trans: 0.15
 * /DWAPlannerROS/min_vel_x: -0.1
 * /DWAPlannerROS/min_vel_y: -0.1
 * /DWAPlannerROS/occdist_scale: 0.02
 * /DWAPlannerROS/oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05
 * /DWAPlannerROS/path_distance_bias: 32.0
 * /DWAPlannerROS/publish_cost_grid_pc: True
 * /DWAPlannerROS/publish_traj_pc: True
 * /DWAPlannerROS/scaling_speed: 0.25
 * /DWAPlannerROS/sim_time: 2.0
 * /DWAPlannerROS/stop_time_buffer: 0.2
 * /DWAPlannerROS/vth_samples: 40
 * /DWAPlannerROS/vx_samples: 20
 * /DWAPlannerROS/vy_samples: 0
 * /DWAPlannerROS/xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
 * /DWAPlannerROS/yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.2
 * /amcl/base_frame_id: base_link
 * /amcl/initial_pose_a: 0
 * /amcl/initial_pose_x: 0
 * /amcl/initial_pose_y: 0
 * /amcl/map_frame_id: map
 * /amcl/odom_frame_id: odom
 * /amcl/odom_topic: odom
 * /amcl/scan_topic: scan
 * /cost_scaling_factor: 4.5
 * /footprint: [[0.35, 0.25], [0...
 * /global_costmap/global_costmap/robot_base_frame: base_link
 * /global_costmap/global_frame: map
 * /global_costmap/publish_frequency: 10.0
 * /global_costmap/robot_base_frame: base_link
 * /global_costmap/static_map: True
 * /global_costmap/transform_tolerance: 0.5
 * /global_costmap/update_frequency: 10.0
 * /inflation_radius: 1.0
 * /local_costmap/global_frame: odom
 * /local_costmap/height: 4.0
 * /local_costmap/local_costmap/robot_base_frame: base_link
 * /local_costmap/publish_frequency: 10.0
 * /local_costmap/resolution: 0.05
 * /local_costmap/robot_base_frame: base_link
 * /local_costmap/rolling_window: True
 * /local_costmap/static_map: True
 * /local_costmap/transform_tolerance: 0.5
 * /local_costmap/update_frequency: 10.0
 * /local_costmap/width: 4.0
 * /map_type: costmap
 * /move_base/base_global_planner: navfn/NavfnROS
 * /move_base/base_local_planner: base_local_planne...
 * /move_base/conservative_reset_dist: 3.0
 * /move_base/controller_frequency: 10.0
 * /move_base/controller_patience: 15.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/robot_base_frame: base_link
 * /move_base/local_costmap/robot_base_frame: base_link
 * /move_base/odom_frame_id: odom
 * /move_base/oscillation_distance: 0.2
 * /move_base/oscillation_timeout: 10.0
 * /move_base/planner_frequency: 5.0
 * /move_base/planner_patience: 5.0
 * /move_base/recovery_behaviors: [{'name': 'conser...
 * /move_base/shutdown_costmaps: False
 * /observation_sources: scan
 * /obstacle_range: 1.0
 * /raytrace_range: 3.5
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.16.0
 * /scan/clearing: True
 * /scan/data_type: LaserScan
 * /scan/marking: True
 * /scan/sensor_frame: lidar_frame
 * /scan/topic: scan

NODES
  /
    amcl (amcl/amcl)
    map_server (map_server/map_server)
    move_base (move_base/move_base)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[map_server-1]: started with pid [33597]
process[amcl-2]: started with pid [33598]
process[move_base-3]: started with pid [33599]
[ WARN] [1710397714.978719222, 539.147000000]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: canTransform: target_frame map does not exist.. canTransform returned after 539.147 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1710397715.570347861, 539.646000000]: global_costmap: Parameter "plugins" not provided, loading pre-Hydro parameters
[ INFO] [1710397715.574028755, 539.649000000]: global_costmap: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [1710397715.579194562, 539.654000000]:     Subscribed to Topics: 
[ INFO] [1710397715.584528481, 539.659000000]: global_costmap: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[ WARN] [1710397715.609012731, 539.681000000]: local_costmap: Parameter "plugins" not provided, loading pre-Hydro parameters
[ INFO] [1710397715.611611374, 539.683000000]: local_costmap: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [1710397715.613003283, 539.684000000]:     Subscribed to Topics: 
[ INFO] [1710397715.617215776, 539.688000000]: local_costmap: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[ INFO] [1710397715.634702334, 539.703000000]: Created local_planner base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS
[ INFO] [1710397715.638301247, 539.706000000]: Sim period is set to 0.10
[ WARN] [1710397715.641132672, 539.709000000]: Trajectory Rollout planner initialized with param meter_scoring not set. Set it to true to make your settings robust against changes of costmap resolution.
[ INFO] [1710397715.860073172, 539.906000000]: Recovery behavior will clear layer 'obstacles'
[ INFO] [1710397715.860813940, 539.906000000]: Recovery behavior will clear layer 'obstacles'
[ INFO] [1710397715.883876917, 539.925000000]: odom received!
```